# Opengl Constant angle

Tags: c#, opengl

I am able to rotate y axes with mouse event, but I want to constant angle as on 2 screenshot that I shared. I want to always look this angle

[image]

Initial settings;

````
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST); //clear buffers to preset values
            Gl.glClearColor(200, 200, 200, 0);

            /* Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

              Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING_BIT);

              Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);*/




            Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_ONE, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);

            Gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // load the identity matrix
                                                 // load the identity 
            Gl.glTranslated(left_right, up_down, sabit3D);
            Gl.glRotated(xrot, xRotate, yRotate, zRotate); ```
````

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, please upload the screenshot in an [edit] of your question.

Comment: okay I editted.